# Estimating Differential entropy from unbiased samples of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory

If I can get N unbiased samples $x$ from $p(x)$ how can I approximate the Differential entropy:

$$H(X) = -\displaystyle\int_{x} p(x)\log p(x) dx$$

I'm not very knowledgeable in statistics so I'm not sure whether or not this is possible without making assumptions about the form of $p(x)$.

I forgot to mention that $X$ is a **continuous** random variable.

*EDIT: Changed to Differential entropy thanks to correction from @gunes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for continuous variables, we actually calculate *differential entropy*, which is denoted as $h(X)$ in general.

When you have samples, you can construct a histogram. There may be various approaches after then. You can fit a parametric distribution if its shape is tameable, which means you need to make some assumptions of the form of $p(x)$, obtain parameters and perform the usual integration. Or, you can estimate $p(x)$ via a non-parametric method like [KDE](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kernel_density_estimation), and after that perform numeric integration to find $h(X)$.

Comment: Is there any parametric method in which I can compute the entropy or integral in closed form? Maybe Gaussian process?

Comment: If the shape is familiar, i.e. resembles well known distributions, choose one and estimate density parameters via MLE. Or, use Gaussian Mixture Models, which assumes the data is generated from a mixture of Gaussians, and you need to decide on the number of components. In either way, plot the fitted $p(x)$ over your sample histogram and convince yourself that it is a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

If you observe $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ as realisations from $p(x)$, the average
$$\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log x_i$$is an unbiased and converging estimator of $H$.

Comment: I know what you're saying works in the limit of n to $\inf$ but I think assuming the distribution is smooth and continuous works better in the finite data regime.